# MySQL: Simple Query Modification

Tags: mysql

There are these three tables:

1. posts
2. posts_replies
3. likes

This query is returning me posts and their replies count all fine.

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.num, posts.status, posts.category, posts.content, posts.member_num, COUNT( posts_replies.blyrb_num ) AS count, COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM posts_replies
INNER JOIN posts ON ( posts_replies.blyrb_num = posts.num )
LEFT JOIN likes ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE posts.status <>3
AND posts.access = 'Public'
AND (
posts.title LIKE '%dress%'
OR posts.content LIKE '%dress%'
)
GROUP BY posts.num
```

But the problem is this query is returning only posts that have some replies. I don't want such restriction, i want all posts whether they have replies or not.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swapping the table in 'FROM' and your first 'JOIN', and changing your first 'JOIN' to a LEFT JOIN, should do the trick:

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.num, posts.status, posts.category, posts.content, posts.member_num, COUNT( posts_replies.blyrb_num ) AS count, COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN posts_replies ON ( posts_replies.blyrb_num = posts.num )
LEFT JOIN likes ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE posts.status <>3
AND posts.access = 'Public'
AND (
posts.title LIKE '%dress%'
OR posts.content LIKE '%dress%'
)
GROUP BY posts.num
```

Answer (score 1):

Things to do:

- use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`
- interchange the tables: `POST` and `posts_replies`

Query,

```
SELECT  posts.title, 
        posts.num, 
        posts.status, 
        posts.category, 
        posts.content, 
        posts.member_num, 
        COUNT( posts_replies.blyrb_num ) AS count, 
        COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM    posts
        LEFT JOIN posts_replies 
            ON ( posts_replies.blyrb_num = posts.num )
        LEFT JOIN likes 
            ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE   posts.status <> 3 AND 
        posts.access = 'Public'
        AND 
        (
            posts.title LIKE '%dress%'
            OR posts.content LIKE '%dress%'
        )
GROUP   BY posts.num
```